# SearchView in 2 activity

Tags: android, searchview

know anyone how can I split my seach view in 2 activity? Before the click on search icon you are in one activity and after you click on it you will be in anther activity were you can write what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose you should build tow **Fragment** as I understood your question.
you write your code about searching (EditView, Button etc.) and code about result in second fragment.

after user click on your Button, you change you pass Data to second fragment and show the search result.
with this structure you can use this fragment for landscape form of your activity to search and show in one screen cross each other. 
is this clear or i explain more dear friend?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, simply show the search icon in the "menu" (i.e. in the toolbar) and in,
OnOptionsItemSelected() method call the new activity(i.e. search activity )